# Pasting from OS X clipboard manager into emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, clipboard

I love emacs. I love having my clipboard history. I've used [Jumpcut](http://jumpcut.sf.net) for a long time and recently purchased the powerpack for [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) and tried its clipboard manager.

I have the same problem with both of these clipboard managers. When I try to paste into Emacs, the clipboard manager sends a virtual <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to Emacs. Emacs interprets this as `M-v` -- scroll-down.

I've been using Emacs too long and on too many platforms to change my keybindings. 
Emacs is very customizable. Since clipboard managers are used by geeky power users, the *developers* of clipboard managers are even geekier and know about solving geeky problems.

So, there must be a way to get these things to work together.

Is there a way to configure emacs to accept the paste natively (w/o changing my keybdindings)?

Is there a way for Jumpcut, Alfred, or another clipboard manager to send something that Emacs will interpret (e.g. `C-y`) just for Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Mac, on Windows I solved it by rebindig C-v which I luckily don't use otherwise. But here's an idea:

I guess there are tools for Mac which allows you to bind any key to call an application and check which window is active (something like [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)). Choose some hotkey which you will use to to invoke the clipboard manager (you can also use its current hotkey if your keyboard macro program can handle it). Attach a macro to the hotkey which checks which window is active and if it is emacs then it sends a message first to emacs via emacsclient to rebind M-v as "yank and then restore the original binding of M-v" and then invokes the clipboard manager. This way when the clipboard manager pastes into emacs then emacs will interpret M-v as yank and then it restores the original binding of M-v to scrolling.

Comment: Wow... macro-processor sending message to emacs for dynamic key rebinding. Serious emacs/geeky chops to you. Have an upvote. I'll have to explore my options in OS X before I accept this though.

Comment: you don't use C-v??? how do you page down?

Answer (score 0):

The source for Jumpcut (which I have never used) is available, so you can change `fakeCommandV` in `AppController.m` to detect when it's pasting in Emacs.  I have tested the following very lightly.  I also had to make a few unrelated but minor changes to get it to compile on my computer (10.6).

```
-(void)fakeCommandV
    /*" +fakeCommandV synthesizes keyboard events for Cmd-v Paste
    shortcut. "*/
    // Code from a Mark Mason post to Cocoadev-l
    // What are the flaws in this approach?
    //  We don't know whether we can really accept the paste
    //  We have no way of judging whether it's gone through
    //  Simulating keypresses could have oddball consequences (for instance, if something else was trapping control v)
    //  Not all apps may take Command-V as a paste command (xemacs, for instance?)
    // Some sort of AE-based (or System Events-based, or service-based) paste would be preferable in many circumstances.
    // On the other hand, this doesn't require scripting support, should work for Carbon, etc.
    // Ideally, in the future, we will be able to tell from what environment JC was passed the trigger
    // and have different behavior from each.
{
    NSString* app = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activeApplication]
                     objectForKey:@"NSApplicationName"];
    NSLog(@"Current application: %@",app);
    if ( [app isEqual:@"Emacs"] ) {
        NSNumber *keyCode = [srTransformer reverseTransformedValue:@"Y"];
        CGKeyCode yCode = (CGKeyCode)[keyCode intValue];
        CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)59, true ); // Control down
        CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)'y', yCode, true ); // Y down
        CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)'y', yCode, false ); //  Y up
        CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)59, false ); // Control up

    } else {
        NSNumber *keyCode = [srTransformer reverseTransformedValue:@"V"];
        CGKeyCode veeCode = (CGKeyCode)[keyCode intValue];
        CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)55, true ); // Command down
        CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)'v', veeCode, true ); // V down
        CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)'v', veeCode, false ); //  V up
        CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)55, false ); // Command up
    }
}
```